# Simultaneous regression of multiple curves in the same dataset or image?

Tags: pattern-recognition

[image: dataset with multiple lines]
I am getting the pattern shown in the picture from an experiment. To my human brain it is evident that it consists of some 20 straight lines. I need to find position and slope of all these lines (perform a regression). But I need to do it completely automatically. If this were a a single sequence I would have used RLS(Recursive Least Squares) or Kalman filter. But how can I go about if I want to make 20 simultaneous regressions that do not conflict with each other?

What would be the most generic way to solve these kind of problems (say if I have an image of 20 overlapping boxes and need to find size, position and angle of all of them, at once)? I suppose the solution is more than well-known since this would be fundamental for any image recognition, but I cannot find a generic description of the method.

Comment: Though this is not a general case, I can accept straight lines as hypothesis and then proceed proving or disproving it. Do you have any reference to a simple implementation of a line detector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible methods.  In your picture, there aren't too many dots, so the following algorithm might be good enough:

- For each pair of points, find the line through them.  Count the number of points that are approximately on that line.
- Choose the line that has the most number of points on it.  Output that line.  Delete all points that are approximately on that line from the figure.
- Repeat until no points remain.

For fancier methods (e.g., if you have a huge number of points, or some prior model for what kinds of lines you expect to see), you can look at [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) and the [expectation maximization (EM) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm), but given your sample picture, the above simple method might be adequate in your setting.

Comment: Thanks! RANSAC seems a more straightforward solution for a limited number of points like here, though it may require many attempts to "grip" into the first valid line. EM algorithm looks tougher, but perhaps more powerful in the end. I shall investigate both!

Comment: Found on the RANSAC wiki page a link to [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), which seems to be specifically designed to solve exactly this problem!

Comment: @the_regressor, the Hough transform is going to be basically equivalent to the first method I describe.

Comment: Well, it certainly worked :-) Here are the custom Hough [transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Rf5.png) of the dots and the identified  [lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8rvz.png) overlapped with the original data. Close to perfect!